# Full size picture from Facebook Graph API with Firebase Authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication, facebook-oauth

**I am creating a Web app using ReactJS and Firebase. I am using Firebase Authentication for login**

I have implemented FB Auth using Firebase Auth Successfully. Now what i want to accomplish is to get a larger size profile image rather than the default one. I have tried different techniques but unable to get the desired result.
[The Graph API i want to hit](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cpicture.width(960).height(960)%2Cfirst_name%2Clast_name%2Cemail%26access_token%3D&version=v11.0)

1. Firebase Auth Function

```js
const signUpWithFb = async ()=>{
    console.log("\n Auth Provider Function Start \n");
    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('email');
    await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(async (result)=> {
        console.log("\n Auth Provider before Fetch Function \n");
        await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/me?fields=name,picture.width(960)
        .height(960),first_name,last_name,email&access_token=${result.credential.accessToken}`)
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
            console.log("Response Status:  "+res.status);
            console.log("Response Type:  "+res.type);
            console.log("Response Status Text:  "+res.statusText);
            console.log("Response Body:  ");
            console.log(res.body);
            console.log("Response URL:  "+res.url);
            console.log(res.picture); // give me undefined
            console.log("\n Auth Provider Function End After Fetch Function \n");
        })
    })
}
```

2. [Response i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb0V4.png)

The Problem i am facing is that when i try to hit the Graph API using JavaScript Fetch Method Or react-axios. It gives me
`Response Status:  200
Response Type:  cors
Response Body:
body: ReadableStream
locked: false

-> On Clicking the url form [res.url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRH2D.png).

---

**Please Check the attached Images for Referencing**

1. Response
2. res.url

Thanks

Comment: That's because you specified the API URL wrong - the `//` between the protocol and host name are missing. Correct is of course `https://graph.facebook.com/`

Comment: @CBroe sorry for the typo. I was only on the examples i created to post not in the actual API URL.

Comment: The 400 on that second request is likely because you did not pass any auth token - so how that URL it shows there ends with just `...&access_token=`? You stored the token in the variable `token`, but then here you tried to insert `${accessToken}`

Comment: @CBroe i assign it to useState hooks `const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(" ");`
from react  
`var token = result.credential.accessToken;
setAccessToken(token);` 
so that i can you it anywhere through context API.

Comment: But that clearly did not work. The screenshot shows that no value was inserted into the URL.

Comment: @CBroe [I changed the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gtfx.png). Removed the useState hook. Here is the API [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdi91.png). On Clicking the [Graph API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srsXr.png). The Problem that the API is not called it only attach the accessToken to the URL. Not call the API

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - edit your question instead, and include any relevant new information there, properly formatted.

Comment: @CBroe i have updated the post kindly check it.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is supposed to be now, second screenshot appears to show that you _did_ get data from the API?

Comment: @CBroe i want to get Data in response. Not when i click it. I don't know what is wrong or what i am doing is wrong